# Access html elements created by js in other js functions

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access html elements that I create in one js function in another function. I have this code

EDIT after comments:
here is a jsfiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/8uTxM/

```
</button>" +"<button value='1' type='button' class='as' id='c2' onclick='cA(this);'>"
```

in this function

```
function cA (element){
var x = element.value;

if (x === allQuestions[questionNumber].correctAnswer) {
    element.setAttribute.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    ++score;
    }
}
```

I am trying to make the button green when it is clicked. However, I get the error:
Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

I assume this has something to do with timing, but I cannot figure out why. Especially since the element.value bit works (the++score works fine, every right question adds +1 to the score variable)

Comment: General remark: A HTML element's ID must not start with a number. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html). Most browsers will probably tolerate it, but it's better to avoid going against the rules.

Comment: First off, its getElementById not getElement*s*ById. Second, if you use on click you should define your function as a function (`onclick="functionName();"`). Third, you could try passing the `this` to your function and eliminating the need for separate functions altogether: `onclick="setIndId(this);"`, and then passing it your function `function setIndId(element){ element.setAttribute("id",0+questionNumber)}`. But it's very complicated to figure out like this, so please provide a fiddle or  a reference to your code somewhere (if it is readable and not over complex)

Comment: added jsfiddle in original post

Answer (score 1):

One problem that I may guess is you are using "**getElementsById**"

either go for "**getElementById**" or "**getElementsByTagName**"

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a `<div>` in your html/php page which would be empty with the answers class, and then change its id/innerHTML ?

Comment: I create the div dynamically to hide it more easily. each div gets assigned the question number. When the next button is clicked, the current question is assigned a .hidden class.